# Deploying ML model on Streamlit

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, xgboost, streamlit

I have a code that basically takes in a csv, which can be uploaded from streamlit and then pushes out a classification prediction.

Just as a context I use xgboost to create my model and I save it as following:

```
joblib.dump(model, 'C:\\Users\myname\classification\default_class_model.pkl')
```

To grab the model I do:

```
model_from_joblib =joblib.load('C:\\Users\myname\classification\default_class_model.pkl')
scoring = model_from_joblib.predict(X_test)
```

When I execute it in Jupyter notebooks it seems to work just fine, but when running on  anaconda and do
streamlit run mymodel.py

I  get the error:

> XGBoostError: [13:38:10]
> C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.1.0\include\xgboost/json.h:65:
> Invalid cast, from Null to Array

Does anyone have an idea why this may be?

Comment: Don't use notebook, don't use streamlit, now use only anaconda does model prediction works?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating the xgboost version I was using